# How to iterate through selected items of a checkbox drop-down list and check the value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo-box that accepts multiple values. It is set up like this:

```
[] Empty
[] Math
[] Science
[] English
```

A user can select multiple options. However, when a user selects Empty, then the value should be blank or an empty string. The current implementation allows for the value to be a combination of 'Empty' and an actual subject.

I am using the AfterUpdate() event here

```
Private Sub Classes_Value_AfterUpdate()
Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 0 To MyComboBox.ItemsSelected.Count - 1
  If MyComboBox.ListIndex(counter) = "Empty" Then
    Me.MyComboBox.Value = " " 
End Sub
```

But it doesn't seem to like the `.ListIndex(counter)` line. I can't seem to check the value appropriately in my loop.

Comment: A user cannot select multiple values in a combo box.  Perhaps you mean **listbox** ?

Comment: My combo-box has the option to check multiple values. Once I hit 'Ok' then the value will be the concatenation of all the checked boxes.

Comment: It sounds more like a [Checkbox Dropdown List](https://support.office.com/article/use-a-list-that-stores-multiple-values-c8d15127-3641-45fc-aa2d-a3943d355e89) as opposed to Combobox?

Comment: Yeah, that's more accurate, actually. Let me edit - do you think its solvable?

Comment: Of course, its a new feature of Access.  I haven't used them personally but before I Google it, are you saying you're returned a comma separate string of values that you need to parse each value?  ie, `yourString="Blue,Green,Red"` (or that the `.Value` of the control is `Blue,Green,Red`)?  If so, I have a solution.

Comment: Or, is the issue that you don't want `Empty` to show up if that's selected?  It's kind of a strange setup to have an "Empty" option when using checkboxes, since by definition, no selected checkboxes means it's "empty"

Comment: (also I'd suggest re-wording the question as well as the title.  This is not a combo box.)

Comment: So, if the user selects Empty, then I want the value itself to just display 'Empty', even if they selected Math and Science as well. So, if the .Value contains 'Empty' then I want it to just read as Empty. But if it doesn't contain Empty, then continue with the concatenation.

Comment: That will make for a confusing UI, unless its just for your own use...

Comment: So "Empty" represents actually that no value was selected. Why then would you want to include a value Empty? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ashleedawg I know them as multi-valued combo boxes. The object type (in vba) is `Access.Combobox`, they're just sort-of hacked in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Value` property of the multi-valued combo box. That's an array of all selected values.

```
Private Sub Classes_Value_AfterUpdate()
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v To MyComboBox.Value
      If v = "Empty" Then
        Me.MyComboBox.Value = Null
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use this, but from an UX view, I highly recommend you don't use it and add a *Clear* button instead to set the field to `Null`.